# Break down to 3 columns

Tags: sql

I have a table with 2 columns

```
sid     location
1       ROANOKE VA_VA1011 
2       ALAMOGORDO NM_NM1000
```

I want to break location in to 3 columns like this

```
sid     location                 city        state    zip  
1       ROANOKE VA_VA1011        ROANOKE     VA       VA1011  
2       ALAMOGORDO NM_NM1000     ALAMOGORDO  NM       NM1000
```

my code

```
Select a.sid, a.location, B.*
 From  table A
 Cross Apply (
                Select city = xDim.value('/x[2]','varchar(50)')
                      ,state = xDim.value('/x[3]','varchar(50)')
                      ,zip= xDim.value('/x[4]','varchar(50)')
                From  ( values (cast('<x>' + replace(location,' ','</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml)))  A(xDim)
             ) B
```

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (Your query is product specific in several ways.)

Comment: You seem to forget to ask your question.

Comment: I want to create location in to 3 columns

Comment: Generally speaking SQL is not the right tool to do language processing.

Comment: Will your location column have just one `underscore`?

Comment: mainly for space and underscore (if you can)

Comment: `CHARINDEX` combined with substring and len would do the trick (presuming you always have an underscore). Not the prettiest, but doable. For example: `substring(location, 1, charindex('_', location) - 4) as city`

Comment: Ii can break down the city but not underscore like this VA_VA1011

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you always have an underscore then this works. Written in sql server, adjust as needed.

```
select 
 sid, 
 location, 
 substring(location, 1, charindex('_', location) - 4) as city, 
 substring(location, charindex('_', location) -2, 2) as state, 
 right(location, 6) as zip, 
 right(location, len(location) - charindex('_', location)) as zip2 --if zip is not always 6
from table1
```

| sid | location | city | state | zip | zip2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | ROANOKE VA_VA1011 | ROANOKE | VA | VA1011 | VA1011 |
| 2 | ALAMOGORDO NM_NM1000 | ALAMOGORDO | NM | NM1000 | NM1000 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/xnPWtVR5)

Comment: Excellent!, that's fine with me. Thank you so much.